# npgsql - stop using 'template1' database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I want to use elephantsql database with entity framework (whichever version). I found tutorial on the internet about npgsql which can help me connect those 2 piece of technology.

I made an object which will represent object from DB :

```
[Table("typychorob", Schema = "public")]
public class TypChoroby
{
    public TypChoroby()
    {
    }

    [Key, Column("id"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("nazwa"), MaxLength(50)]
    public string Nazwa { get; set; }
}
```

I created class which will represent dBContext. Uzytkownik is nearly the same as TypChoroby.

```
public class PrzychodniaContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Uzytkownik> Uzytkownicy { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TypChoroby> TypyChorob { get; set; }

    public PrzychodniaContext() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

I try to use those things in the following style :

```
using (var context = new PrzychodniaContext())
        {
            context.Database.Log = post;
            var chorobska = context.TypyChorob.ToList();
        }
```

This always creates error like this :

```
{"28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host \"178.37.126.100\", user \"jnwnqqog\", database \"template1\", SSL off"}
```

It's elephantSql simplest plan so i cannot edit pg_hba.conf which is a file where i can give myself some privileges.

My ConnectionString :

```
<add name="PrzychodniaContext" connectionString="Server=YouDontWantToKnowButYouKnow;Database=jnwnqqog;User Id=jnwnqqog;Password=YouDontWantToKnow;MAXPOOLSIZE=5;" providerName="Npgsql" />
```

What i tried?

1) First i know what's going on. In documentation of npgsql in create database command i found :

```
template
The name of the template from which to create the new database, or DEFAULT to use the default template (template1).
```

Honetsly i do not know how to change that. I though that it would be good to change that to 'jnwnqqog', because it's my DB at elephantSQL. But i do not know.

2) I'd used
    Database.SetInitializer(null);
I assumed that it will stop trying to create new database. It did not stopped this behaviour.

3) I tried to enable/disable SSL.

4) I changed entity framework from 5.0 to 6.0 along with npgsql.

For all curious :
-why elephantsql and postgresql with visual studio? - university project. Honestly i would like to use mssql but i cannot. Only progresql.

Edit : I tried to read many questions/tutorials/bug tracker stories/etc. Did not find my answer.
Edit2 : Sorry i forgot. ElephantSQL is an postgresql database hosted in cloud.

Comment: What's this "elephantSQL" thing?

Comment: ElephantSQL is an postgresql database hosted in cloud.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I made it :).

If someone ever will have same problem as me then you need to add this to your connection string:

```
EntityAdminDatabase=[DATABASE_NAME]
```

Then it will stop using 'template1'.

Comment: Wow this was very helpfull where does this parameter comes from ?

Answer (score 4):

Updating npgsql dll and adding EntityAdminDatabase=[DATABASE_NAME] in connection string Works for me.

Thank's