# "No such database" error on pgAdmin when connecting through pgbouncer

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, pgbouncer

I have configured pgbouncer on server A(**port 6432, host addr: 10.XX.XX.92**) that will accept the connections for postgres server running on server B(**port 5433, host addr:10.XX.XX.90**). This postgres server has 2 databases.(**postgres and db1**)

I have 2 different type of users(user1, user2) that will connect to same database(db1). These both users have different set of permissions on db1.

Below is the sample of how I have configured pgbouncer.ini file.

*database1 = host=10.XX.XX.90 port=5433 user=user1 password='pwd1' dbname=db1

database2 = host=10.XX.XX.90 port=5433 user=user2 password='pwd2' dbname=db1*

Now when I try to connect to this database through pgAdmin it gives me an error of **"No such database"** .

Below are the connection variables that I used to connect through pgadmin for user1.

**host = 10.XX.XX.92

port = 6432

maintenance database = database1

username = user1

password = pwd1**

But when I use same variables and try to connect using DBeaver or psql, I am able to connect to the database db1 successfully.

Does anyone know if this is just pgAdmin issue or am I missing something here.

**Note:** There is one more thing I tried. If in the pgbouncer.ini, I name the database variable(database1) same as actual database name(db1), pg
Admin lets me connect to the database. This would have worked for me if I just had one user connecting to the database but I have two users and they both can't have same connection name in the config file.

Comment: Do you have some sort of port forwarding setup on DBeaver or psql? I've seen this error with port numbers not matching and in your example you have `5433` and `6432`.

Comment: No. I was just able to connect to the database directly without setting up anything explicitly. I think this is something related to maintenance database in pgAdmin but I might be wrong.

Comment: I've got the same problem. After all this time did you fix it ?
Edit : think I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41500185/5341247

Answer (score 0):

Have a try here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41500185/5341247

add this to your connection string :

`EntityAdminDatabase=DATABASE_NAME`